# GraphView not Plotting all points

Tags: android, android-graphview

so am plotting a graph using com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView. and from my API am passing only the last 6 value. But the problem is that it does not plot all the 6 it only plot 4 points on the graph and i don't know why.
the code below is a chunk of code from my onPostExecute method in my Asynctask class.

```
                    if (valuationList.size() >6){
                        valuationList = valuationList.subList(valuationList.size() -6,valuationList.size());
                       totalUnitPoint = new ArrayList<>(totalUnitPoint.subList(totalUnitPoint.size() - 6, totalUnitPoint.size()));
                       currentValuePoint = new ArrayList<>(currentValuePoint.subList(currentValuePoint.size() - 6, currentValuePoint.size()));
                    }
                    DataPoint [] cummuDataPointArr = totalUnitPoint.toArray(new DataPoint[totalUnitPoint.size()]);
                    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> cummulativeSeries = new LineGraphSeries<>(cummuDataPointArr);

                    StaticLabelsFormatter staticLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(cummulativeChart);
                    staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(valuationList.toArray(new String[valuationList.size()]));
                    //staticLabelsFormatter.setVerticalLabels(new String[] {"low", "middle", "high"});
                    cummulativeChart.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter);

                    cummulativeChart.addSeries(cummulativeSeries);
                    cummulativeSeries.setColor(R.color.royal_blue);
                    cummulativeChart.setTitle("Units Acquired");
                    cummulativeChart.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalAxisTitle("Cummulative Units");
                    cummulativeChart.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalAxisTitle("Months");

                    cummulativeSeries.setDrawDataPoints(true);
                    cummulativeSeries.setDataPointsRadius(10);
                    cummulativeSeries.setThickness(2);

                    DataPoint [] currentDataPointArr = currentValuePoint.toArray(new DataPoint[currentValuePoint.size()]);
                    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> currentSeries = new LineGraphSeries<>(currentDataPointArr);

                    StaticLabelsFormatter currentFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(currentChart);
                    currentFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(valuationList.toArray(new String[valuationList.size()]));
                    currentChart.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(currentFormatter);

                    currentChart.addSeries(currentSeries);
                    currentSeries.setColor(R.color.green);
                    currentChart.setTitle("RSA Balance (Naira)");
                    currentChart.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalAxisTitle("Current Value");
                    currentChart.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalAxisTitle("Months");
                    currentSeries.setDrawDataPoints(true);
                    currentSeries.setDataPointsRadius(10);
                    currentSeries.setThickness(2);
```

Please i need you help to fix this[image: This the current graph results am getting it only plots 4 out of 6 points.]

Comment: can you please strip your code and post only the parts relevant to your question.

Comment: @Psytho i have removed the irrelevant part.

Comment: Are you sure ``cummulativeSeries`` has 6 elements?

Comment: yes am very sure because i debugged it multiple times.